# Update <div> within JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML:-

```
    <div id="something" class="col-md-2 hideOverflow">
        @Html.Label(@Address.label_AddressType)
    </div>
```

with the following script:-

```
    function pageLoad() {
        $('[data-toggle="popoverHover"]').popover({ trigger: 'hover', placement: 'top' });
        $('[data-toggle="popoverClick"]').popover({ trigger: 'click', placement: 'top' });

        $('.something').attr('data-toggle', 'popoverHover');
        $('.something').attr('data-content', 'Testing 123');
    }
```

Please would someone assist me with getting the text 'Testing 123' to appear on hover-over of the label.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to giving **lable attribute** `title` , **title** will show when you hover over the **lable**

Comment: I would only need the title to show when it exceeds the width of the <div> container it resides in.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a popover using the constructor like

```js
function pageLoad() {
  $('[data-toggle="popoverHover"]').popover({
    trigger: 'hover',
    placement: 'top'
  });
  $('[data-toggle="popoverClick"]').popover({
    trigger: 'click',
    placement: 'top'
  });
  $('.something').popover({
    trigger: 'hover',
    placement: 'top',
    content: 'Testing 123'
  });

}

pageLoad();
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<br />
<br />
<div data-toggle="popoverHover" data-content="on hover">data-toggle="popoverHover"</div>
<div data-toggle="popoverClick" data-content="on click">data-toggle="popoverClick"</div>
<label class="something">something</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script doesn't work, because you're using a class selector instead of id selector. Also, popover does not appear, because you initialize it on the element, which does not exist in DOM at the moment, when you call `jQuery.fn.popover`. Therefore, you have to add `data-toggle="popoverHover"` before initializing the script.

You will easily fix this by reordering your code and changing the selector:

```
function pageLoad() {

  // Add the attributes by calling .attr() once.
  $('#something').attr({
    'data-toggle': 'popoverHover',
    'data-content': 'Testing 123'
  });

  $('[data-toggle="popoverHover"]').popover({
    trigger: 'hover',
    placement: 'top'
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks halfzebra ... now for another dimension to this question - is there a way of only showing the popoverHover when the length of @Html.Label(@Address.label_AddressType) exceeds the <div> that it resides in?

Comment: @Sox just to clarify, do you want to show the popover right away, if @Html.Label(@Address.label_AddressType) is longer than some amount of caracters?

Comment: No, only display the popoverHover when hovering over the label when it exceeds the width of the <div> it sits in. The label is already truncated with ellipsis in the <div>.

Comment: @Sox Please have a look, I'm not sure if that's exactly what you want http://jsfiddle.net/ya5y009d/2/

Comment: Very close. I need it only to display the popover when the label has been truncated due to its length.

Comment: @Sox Please have a look http://jsfiddle.net/e5v790h5/ have in mind that the script will check the condition only once. I have changed `col-md-1` to `.col-xs` class for better visibility.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, it is working as expected but with one problem. `@Html.Label(@Address.label_AddressType)` is obtained from a resource file and this results in the popoverHover not activating. If I replace it with hard-coding `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.` it activates. Do you perhaps have an idea why?

Comment: @Sox would be nice to have an example with real data, it's hard to tell what's wrong.

Comment: have you got an email that I may send to you?

Comment: @Sox No, I don't think so, you can update the question and I will do whatever I can to help you

Comment: I have a resource file called `Address.resx` with `Name = label_AddressType` and `Value = Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.`

Comment: I have a webpage called `Address.html` with reference `@using App_Resources.Client.Address`. It contains HTML as follows:-`<div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row bottom-padded-5">
            <div id="addressType" class="col-md-2 hideOverflow">
                <span class="text">@Html.Label(@Address.label_AddressType)</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`

Comment: The sample code you provided works perfectly when 'hard-coded' values are in the `<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>` tags, however when I use `<span class="text">@Html.Label(@Address.label_AddressType)</span>` the popoverHover functionality does not work,

Comment: @Sox sorry, I have misunderstood you, you can mail me anytime, I'm just not checking it that often half.zebra at gmail or find me here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript

Comment: many thanks. I will put it into a separate project when I have a moment and send it to you. Thanks for your assistance.